# Why are there two categories of instances in AWS for Compute and Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Relatively new to AWS. Initially I thought RDS instances are similar to databases but later got to know that they are also just another instances like EC2 even though RDS is mainly projected only for databases

And if my understanding is right databases running on EC2 instances are not fully managed by AWS whereas databases running on RDS instances are fully managed by AWS except the optimization of the running application which should be done by the user

But my question is already there are 300+ EC2 instance types in AWS. If this is the case then why RDS instances (i.e instances specifically meant for database applications) are not inducted into one of the EC2 instance types and what is the advantage or primary reason to categorize them as a separate category altogether ?

Answer (score 1):

Databases typically run better with lots of Memory (for cache).

The available families are currently:

- **t3:** Good for dev/test, not great for Production (because they can be CPU-limited) -- Would be better if they used the newer-generation t4g
- **m6g:** Good combination of CPU & Memory, using Graviton processes for better value
- **m5:** Older generation, legacy use only
- **r6g:** Lots of memory relative to CPU, again using Graviton
- **r5:** Older generation, legacy use only

Other instance families don't necessarily make sense for a database:

- **Compute optimized (C family):** Databases are rarely CPU-limited
- **Storage optimized:** RDS uses Amazon EBS for storing, not Instance Store